# Did the current Marvel TV Shows have to change plans because of the "Infinity War" fallout?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, agents-of-shield, daredevil-tv, luke-cage

[image: Marvel TV]

**Season 5** of **[Agents of Shield](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2364582/)** is currently airing, **Season 2** of **[Luke Cage](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3322314/)** comes out this June  and **Season 3** of **[Daredevil](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3322312/)** is also expected to be released later this year.

Since what happens at the end of **[Avengers: Infinity War](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/)** has major consequences for Earth, it made me wonder if the showrunners of the Marvel TV shows were given advance notice? Did they already know what was going to happen in **Infinity War** when they planned their storylines or did they have to adjust things to fit with the movie's continuity?

To be clear, I'm not asking how or if the TV shows will address the **Infinity War** fallout, I'm just asking whether the showrunners had to *change* already planned storylines of if they knew what was going to happen *before* they started production on their currents seasons.

**My question:**

- Were the showrunners of the Marvel TV shows given enough advance notice or did they have to adjust their original ideas for their currents seasons (e.g. set it *before* the events of Infinity War)?

Comment: Considering the Netflix shows still hasn't come to Civil War timeline and the current Agents of SHIELD occurs in space, I don't think Infinity War will have huge ramifications so soon...

Comment: All in good times lads.. -Marvel

Comment: @NikhilEshvar - The latest __Jessica Jones__ season referenced __Spider-Man__. - And __Agents of Shield__ is no longer in space, in fact, the last episode had a line about _"weird stuff happening in New York"_, which was probably an Infinity War reference.

Comment: That said - http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/agents-of-shield/news/a853655/agents-shield-showrunner-confirms-events-avengers-infinity-war-will-catch-shields-attention/

Comment: @Paulie_D - I specifically say that my questions isn't about how or if the TV shows will be addressing "Infinity War", but about whether the showrunners got a heads up or if they had to change their original plans.

Comment: Agents of SHIELD, in its latest episode did mention New York but didn't elaborate on it. May be they take place before Infinity War since everything except SHIELD is only indirectly in MCU

Comment: @Paulie_D - If AOS's season finale addresses the Infinity War fallout, is it because the showrunners got a heads up, or did they originally have a different endgame in mind and had to rewrite it. - Similar with DD/LC, did they already know about the end of Infinity War and plan their seasons accordingly (whether they deal with the fallout or not) or did they have to change their original plans? - That's not something that can be infered from watching the shows, but maybe the showrunners have spoken about it in interviews?

Comment: The follwoing is just decent speculation about how the TV series *could, especially Netflix series, may deal (or not deal) with Infinity War: https://screenrant.com/avengers-infinity-war-marvel-tv-shield-netflix-affect/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per this [link](https://screenrant.com/mcu-tv-shows-timeline-avengers-infinity-war/), Jeph Loeb, Marvel's head of TV, and thus the man responsible for the content of the Netflix shows, Agents of SHIELD, Cloak And Dagger, etc etc has confirmed that "almost all of" the TV shows are pre-snap.

This was answered during a [Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/8pbxyk/im_jeph_loeb_head_of_marvel_tv_ama/e0a5ju5/) and is because of the different schedules of production etc

> For the most part our stories will take place BEFORE Thanos clicked
>   his fingers. A lot of that has to do with production and when we are
>   telling our stories vs. when the movies come out. So hang in there. I
>   remember in the comics, one of my favorite stories was the KREE-SKRULL
>   war... which was universal, but in X-Men, no mention. Huh. And it all
>   worked out in the end.

This does, however, indicate that perhaps there will be some stories which will deal with the impact - but there's nothing to suggest which at this time.

Comment: The quote does sound like they didn't want to compromise their own stories and therefore sidestepped the finger snap.

Answer (score 1):

The Netflix shows have only paid lip service to the events in any of the MCU movies (i.e in Luke Cage the guys selling footage of the "incident in New York), so they probably won't reference it.

AoS on the other hand has been deeply effected by the events of the MCU (Coulson's resurrection, Nick Fury, Lady Sif, Winter Soldier / Hydra, Civil War / Sokovia accord etc.), so it's highly likely that they will at least reference it in the future (if the show gets renewed for Season 6).

Regarding the showrunners, who knows? I'd say that there's little communication between Disney and Netflix, but as ABC is owned by Disney, they probably get some kind of notice and direction, hence those 'crossovers' mentioned above.

Comment: _"... so they probably won't reference it."_ How can they ignore that 50% of the world population is gone? - But either way, my question is about whether the showrunners got advance notice or if they had to do rewrites.

Comment: When is Luke Cage set? Its after Avengers Assemble, but beyond that do we know when? Might be before the current film.

Comment: Looking at the [Season 2 Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB1in0KkoG4), __Luke Cage__ doesn't seem to be set post "Infinity War". - __Season 2__ was greenlit in __December 2016__, so the "Luke Cage" producers/writers probably started to ponder about Season 2 storylines before "Infinity War" started shooting (__[January 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War#Production)__).

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely you'll get a definitive answer to this, until all of the shows that were in production before and immediately after *Infinity War* was released have aired. Marvel has never said how much information is shared between Marvel Studios and Marvel Television, and I can't think of a reason they ever would do so. So, the only chance of really getting an answer is if someone on the inside decides to talk about it. Of course, if half the people in *Cloak & Dagger* are suddenly gone by the end of its first season, then its writers would have obviously had advance knowledge of what happened in *IW*, since *C&D* finished filming last Fall.

I will say that my guess is that the showrunners probably weren't given advanced notice. Since Marvel Studios was separated from Marvel Entertainment (the parent of Marvel Television), the TV shows haven't seemed to have much interest in connecting with the movies. There hasn't been more than vague references to them. The heads of the newer shows like *Cloak & Dagger* and *New Warriors* have given interviews that make it sound like they just don't want to think about the broader universe.

I imagine that Marvel Television would like to completely ignore the events of *Infinity War*. As you said, it seems hard to ignore half the population disappearing, though, so they might be forced to. But even if so, they'll probably wait to do so. The timelines of their current shows are either noticeably in the past (e.g., the Netflix shows), or are ambiguous enough that they could be taking place before *IW*. And, if they can wait until after *Avengers 4* is released, since that movie will almost definitely undo the finger snap, the shows might be able to get away with not referencing it.

Assuming that's their mindset, there wouldn't be a need for them to know about the events of *IW* in advance. And without a need, I'm sure Marvel Studios wouldn't have given out any details.

Comment: As Agents of Shields season 6 has been pushed back until mid 2019 so it does seem like they are planning to start post Avengers 4 presuming it corrects things. The show runners have already said season 5 ends before the snap.

Comment: Last year __Jeph Loeb__ (head of Marve TV) [said](http://ew.com/tv/2017/01/13/defenders-marvel-cinematic-universe-crossover-jeph-loeb/): _"__We certainly communicate with each other in terms of what we’re doing and what we have planned__ and the characters that we’re using and where it’s all going"_

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really answer the question. Obviously they have to talk to each other about which characters are being used since the TV shows can't use any for major roles, that are planned for movie roles. And "where it's all going" is pretty high level, and I think everyone pretty much assumes that. "What we're doing and what we have planned" _could_ answer the question, but it's just too vague. Is "what we have planned" something like "All the heroes from all the movies will fight Thanos, and many will die," or is it "Half the universe's population is killed?"